# Performance issue on rending large number of markers with polylines in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

To render a large number of simple (two point) polylines with markers on a map getting performance issue.

**Example (Tested on Firefox):**

To place 30,000 markers and 15,000 simple polylines, it’s taking time to render.

To solve this (streaming data): Adding 250 polylines and 500 markers on every 2 seconds instead of adding all the markers and polylines.  But after rendering the all markers and polylines, browse is not responding on zoom in/zoom out.

Is there an easy solution to this?

Tried with MarkerClusterer (markers and polylines) but after zoom in / zoom out the browse was not able to render and crashed.

Tried with only markers (no polylines), giving good performance. It was able to render and able to zoom in /zoom out. 
Are there any limitations or performance issues on combination of markers and polylines?

Could anyone advise on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Sree

Comment: Everytime you pan or zoom the map the position of each overlay(e.g. marker, polyline, polygon) has to be recalculated, that of course will take some time when you have 45k overlays. You better use a FusionTableLayer(when possible).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried with Fusion Table Layer but it requires data to be uploaded to Google drive (if I’m not wrong). I can't upload any data as it is not safe.